# How to fix INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE errors?

Tags: android

I'm not sure exactly why it's causing a problem but the [Datamax Printer SDK](http://www.datamax-oneil.com/do/com/en-us/home/service-support/technical-resources&p=78BF687A-B903-0951-A5DC4C57D04BACE2#SM1) jar causes the apk to fail to install on x86 phones, failing with the error `INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE`.

There are other questions about this error, but most of the advice relates binaries compiled with the NDK.

So, given that this isn't a problem with an NDK binary, is there anything I can do other than bug the manufacturer for an update?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but it kind of sounds as if the Datamax Printer SDK wasn't built to be compatible with the Intel versions of Android and only supports the ARM based. It may be worth contacting Datamax for help

Comment: @Boardy: Yeah, I've contacted their support, but I don't really expect much from them. I'm hoping that there is _something_ I can do myself.